# Java Heap Space error when exporting spark dataframe to hive database

Tags: hadoop, out-of-memory, pyspark, text-analysis

I am using pyspark to do some text analysis on a table in Hive. I use the following code

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row, HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf, StringType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext
hc = HiveContext(sc)
df=hc.sql("select * from table1")
def cleaning_text(sentence):
   sentence=sentence.lower()
   sentence=re.sub('\'',' ',sentence)
   cleaned=' '.join([w for w in cleaned.split() if not len(w)<=2 ])
   return cleaned

org_val=udf(cleaning_text,StringType())
data=df.withColumn("cleaned",org_val(df.text))

data_1=data.select('uniqueid','cleaned','parsed')#2630789 #2022395
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="cleaned", outputCol="words")
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(data_1)

hc.sql("SET spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false")
hc.sql("create table table2 (uniqueid string, cleaned string, parsed string)")
wordsData.insertInto('table2')
```

I can do

```
words_data.show(2)
```

however as I try to export it, it gives me this error

```
INFO FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
Exception in thread "stdout writer for python" 17/02/02 15:18:44 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for python
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I do not mind if this gets exported as a text file too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running this script on the spark shell which defaults to driver memory of 1g.

I changed it by running the statement below while starting the spark shell

```
pyspark --driver-memory 10g
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

while you are inserting into table you should write the insert statement in the hiveContext as it is writing to a hive table.

`hc.sql("SET spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false")
hc.sql("create table table2 (uniqueid string, cleaned string, parsed string)")
wordsData.registerTempTable("tb1")
val df1 = hc.sql("insert into table table2 select * from tb1")`

If the above one doesn't work or if it is not satisfying to you try the below where you can directly saveAsTable (make sure a table is already created in your desired schema)

`wordsData.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("sample_database.sample_tablename")`
If you get any errors by trying above ones please paste the errors here, i will help you further

Comment: `17/02/02 16:49:47 WARN MemoryManager: Total allocation exceeds 95.00% (948,830,208 bytes) of heap memory
Scaling row group sizes to 24.38% for 29 writers
17/02/02 16:50:17 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for python
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`  This is the error generated